# Count the uppercase letters in a string with Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, count, uppercase

I am trying to figure out how I can count the uppercase letters in a string.

I have only been able to count lowercase letters:

```
def n_lower_chars(string):
    return sum(map(str.islower, string))
```

Example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
Type word: HeLLo                                        
Capital Letters: 3
```

When I try to flip the function above, It produces errors:

```
def n_upper_chars(string):
    return sum(map(str.isupper, string))
```

Comment: re-reading this question, I don't see any reason why `sum(map(str.isupper, string))` should not work

Comment: The code in the question works, at least in python 3.9.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can do this with [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression), and [`str.isupper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper):

```
message = input("Type word: ")

print("Capital Letters: ", sum(1 for c in message if c.isupper()))
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> message = input("Type word: ")
Type word: aBcDeFg
>>> print("Capital Letters: ", sum(1 for c in message if c.isupper()))
Capital Letters:  3
>>>
```

Comment: nice! but what about: `sum(1 for x in message if x.isupper() )` ? I know that True is '1', but seems more elegant to sum integers but booleans, or not?

Comment: Yup - I would also go for the `(sum 1 for x...` approach to make it explicit rather than counting on the nature that booleans happen to have (due to historic reasons) 0/1 integer values ;)

Comment: A related form: `sum(c in string.uppercase for c in message)`

Answer (score 16):

You can use `re`:

```
import re
string = "Not mAnY Capital Letters"
len(re.findall(r'[A-Z]',string))
```

> *5*

Answer (score 13):

Using `len` and `filter` :

```
import string
value = "HeLLo Capital Letters"
len(filter(lambda x: x in string.uppercase, value))
>>> 5
```

Answer (score 8):

I've done some comparisons of the methods above + RE compiled using 
`Python 3.7.4`
For this, I've used the book Alice’s Adventures in Wonderland, by Lewis Carroll from Project Gutenberg.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

# Download 
text = urlopen('https://www.gutenberg.org/files/11/11-0.txt').read().decode('utf-8')
# Split it into the separate chapters and remove table of contents, etc
sep = 'CHAPTER'
chaps = [sep + ch for ch in text.split('CHAPTER') if len(ch) > 1000]
len(chaps)
```

Defined all approaches as functions in order to use them in the loop and keep succinct.

```
import re
import string

def py_isupper(text): 
    return sum(1 for c in text if c.isupper())

def py_str_uppercase(text):
    return sum(1 for c in text if c in string.ascii_uppercase)

def py_filter_lambda(text):
    return len(list(filter(lambda x: x in string.ascii_uppercase, text)))

def regex(text):
    return len(re.findall(r'[A-Z]',text))

# remove compile from the loop
REGEX = re.compile(r'[A-Z]')
def regex_compiled(text):
    return len(REGEX.findall(text))
```

The results are below.

```
%%timeit
cnt = [py_isupper(ch) for ch in chaps]
```

> 7.84 ms ± 69.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%%timeit
cnt = [py_str_uppercase(ch) for ch in chaps]
```

> 11.9 ms ± 94.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%%timeit
cnt = [py_filter_lambda(ch) for ch in chaps]
```

> 19.1 ms ± 499 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%%timeit
cnt = [regex(ch) for ch in chaps]
```

> 1.49 ms ± 13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

```
%%timeit
cnt = [regex_compiled(ch) for ch in chaps]
```

> 1.45 ms ± 8.69 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Answer (score 4):

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
count = len([letter for letter in instring if letter in ascii_uppercase])
```

This is not the fastest way, but I like how readable it is.  Another way, without importing from string and with similar syntax, would be:

```
count = len([letter for letter in instring if letter.isupper()])
```

Comment: I agree. With this I can see whats going on.

Comment: @Stevenson You can also use `uppercase` instead of `ascii_uppercase` if you find that more readable too.  You can read about the differences between the two [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-constants).

Comment: Awesome..That give me a better understanding! great link

Answer (score 4):

```
def n_lower_chars(string):
    return sum(i.isupper() for i in string)
```

sums up the numbers of True values in the generator expression

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
s = raw_input().strip()
count = 1
for i in s:
    if i.isupper():
        count = count + 1
print count
```

Answer (score 0):

The (slightly) fastest method for this actually seems to be membership testing in a frozenset

```
import string
message='FoObarFOOBARfoobarfooBArfoobAR'
s_upper=frozenset(string.uppercase)

%timeit sum(1 for c in message if c.isupper())
>>> 100000 loops, best of 3: 5.75 us per loop

%timeit sum(1 for c in message if c in s_upper)
>>> 100000 loops, best of 3: 4.42 us per loop
```