# Function to count small and Capital letters in a string

Tags: python

I wrote a function which takes a string and gives back the count of small letters and the count of capital letters in that string. The program works for single word but as soon I add two words containing 'space' in between two words, messes things up. spaces counts too. 
What is your thoughts?

```
def myfunc(s):
    s = str(s)

    upperl = 0
    lowerl = 0
    for i in s:
        if i == i.lower():
            lowerl += 1
        if i == i.upper():
            upperl += 1
        if i == ' ':
            continue
    return upperl,lowerl

x = myfunc('hello G')
print (x)
```

from the word 'hello G' we expect upper letter and lower letter
count as `1,5` but that space between two words makes it `2,6`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129830/count-the-uppercase-letters-in-a-string-with-python (NB this solution solves space issue)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `' ' == ' '.upper()` and `' ' == ' '.lower()` are both true, and you're not checking whether you're currently dealing with an alphanumeric character or something else. Instead, you can check whether you're working with a lowercase letter or an uppercase letter.

Try this:

```
def calculate_case_count(string: str):
    string = str(string)
    upper_letter_count = 0
    lower_letter_count = 0
    for letter in string:
        if letter.islower():
            lower_letter_count += 1
        elif letter.isupper():
            upper_letter_count += 1
    return upper_letter_count, lower_letter_count


result = calculate_case_count('hello    G ')
print(result) # (1, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex will be cleaner solution here

```py
import re

def count_letter_cases(text):
    n_lower = len(re.findall("[a-z]", text))
    n_upper = len(re.findall("[A-Z]", text))
    return n_lower, n_upper

print(count_letter_cases("Hello Goat"))
## Result: (7,2)
```

Comment: I'd say there's no need to use regex here, having methods from the builtin `str` class to do this. And by no means it is cleaner than simply mapping these `str` methods to the strings and taking the `sum` (simplest solution I can think of)

Comment: ya, It looks for this case it is not necessary, but it has one benefit, you can similarly extend it to count number or other special characters

Answer (score -1):

```
from collections import Counter

def count_cases(strng):
    counts = Counter(strng)
    upper = 0
    lower = 0
    for char, count in counts.items():
        if char.isupper():
            upper += count
        elif char.islower():
            lower += count
    return (upper, lower)
```

Edit: Removed `string` module. Using internal `islower` and `isupper` methods.